# Change laser range while stage is running

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know how to set the laser range in the world file. But once the world file is executed on stage, I can't find any way to manipulate the value of any properties in that world file. So, my question is, after I execute the world file on stage, then I want to change the laser range while I am running the stage. How can I do so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74044/change-laser-range-while-stage-is-running/) by [vv](https://answers.ros.org/users/6049/vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure this is easily doable in Stage, but a workaround could be to write a small node that subscribes to the scan, truncates the ranges contained as you require, and republishes the scan to another topic. Should be a few lines of Python or C++ code and you don't have to mess with Stage.

Another thing you could do is look at the [laser_filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_filters) package and see if it satisfies your requirements.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vv](https://answers.ros.org/users/6049/vv/) on 2013-08-22**:
I'm not quite understand about the "Scan" that I need to subscribe and publish too. Can you tell me clearer please. what topic that I need to subscribe to and what topic should I publish to? Thanks